# How do i get a bot to recognize a different user from other ones?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I wanted to code my bot so that it recognises me when I do a specific command. So for example, when someone else types the same command, the bot would do something different. Here is the code I've been testing:

```
const { Client, GuildMember, Intents, DiscordAPIError } = require('discord.js');
const { Player, QueryType } = require("discord-player");
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client({
    intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_VOICE_STATES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS]
});

module.exports = {
    name: 'ping',
    description: "Test command",
    execute(message, args){
        client.on("messageCreate", message => {
            if (message.author.user.id = '(the user id gathered from a server for example)'){
                message.channel.send("identity test 1");
            } 
        })
        message.reply('pong!')
    }
}
```

I was expecting this code to recognise my user id and send "identity test 1" with the "pong!" reply, but that didn't happen

Comment: Instead of `message.author.user.id`, you can just use `message.author.id`

Comment: @Caladan yeah I was using that previously but trying to fix my problem I've added .user. It doesn't solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

On the line message.author.user.id you were assigning message.author.user.id to the specified id. Also, message. author does not contain the user, so you would only need message.author.id

```
const { Client, GuildMember, Intents, DiscordAPIError } = require('discord.js'); 
const { Player, QueryType } = require("discord-player"); 
const Discord = require('discord.js'); 
const client = new Discord.Client({ 
    intents: [
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_VOICE_STATES,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES, 
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS
    ] 
}); 
module.exports = { 
    name: 'ping', 
    description: "Test command", 
    execute(message, args){ 
        client.on("messageCreate", message => { 
            if (message.author.id === '(the user id gathered from a server for example)') { 
                message.channel.send("identity test 1"); 
            } 
        }) 
        message.reply('pong!') 
    } 
}
```